# How to replace last char of each words with X using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var str_owner = $("#owner").val();
var owner_length = str_owner.length/2;
var owner = str_owner.slice(0, -5)+"XXXXX";
$("#owner_name").html(owner);
```

In the above code I want to replace exact half of each word with X but here I am replace last 5 char with X and I am getting string like `Mike hXXXXX` but I want like `MiXX husXXX`. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: what there is an odd number of characters in a word? say `Alice`

Comment: If it is odd then it should take it accordingly @lastr2d2

Comment: @Klint please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66417745/how-to-replace-last-char-of-each-words-with-x-using-jquery/66418005#66418005

Answer (score 0):

Split the string first and modify the words you want:

```
let str_owner_words = $('#owner').val().split(' ');
for(let i = 0; i < str_owner_words.length; i++){

  const cut_length = Math.round(str_owner_words[i].length / 2);
  str_owner_words[i] = str_owner_words[i].slice(0, -1 * cut_length) + 
    "X".repeat(cut_length);

}

let result_string = str_owner_words.join(" ");
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Does this meets your requirement?

*Logic*

- Select the contet from dom that needs to be encoded.
- If the value consisit of more that one word, split the individual word at the mid, take the first half of the selected word and append 'X' to the remaining half.
- If the word length is odd (say length is 7 as mentioned in example), fill the first 4 with the actual letters and next 3 with 'X'. If you need it in reverse pattern, i.e, first 3 as actual letters and rest 4 as 'X', use `Math.floor` in the function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#replace').click(function(e) {
    var str_owner = $("#owner").text();
    var split_str = str_owner.split(' ');
    var owner = '';
    split_str.forEach((str) => {
      var owner_length = Math.ceil(str.length/2);
      var owner_visible_str = str.slice(0, owner_length);
      owner += owner_visible_str + 'X'.repeat(str.length - owner_visible_str.length) + ' ';
    })
    $("#owner_name").html(owner);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="owner">John Mark Stephen</p>
<p id="owner_name"></p>
<button id="replace">Replace</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As strings are arrays in JS, you can make two substrings and iterate over second on, and add x for each element of substring 2, in substring 1.

```js
var str = 'monty';
var sub1 = str.substr(0,Math.floor(str.length/2));
var sub2 = str.substr(Math.floor(str.length/2),str.length);

for(let i of sub2){
    sub1 +="x";
}
console.log(sub1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for now.
On purpose I added string of 4,2,1,5 character words.

```js
var str = 'This is a tests'
var strArr = str.split(' ', )
var final_string_arr= [];
let i = 0;
while (strArr.length > i) {
        var this_str_length = parseInt(strArr[i].length/2);
        var remain = strArr[i].length - this_str_length;
        var remStr ="";
        if(this_str_length > 0){
            remStr    = strArr[i].slice(0, -(this_str_length))+"x".repeat(this_str_length);
        }else{
            remStr    = strArr[i];
        }
        final_string_arr.push(remStr);
        i++;
}
console.log(final_string_arr.join(" "));
```